# Adding data to new columns from a previous one

Tags: r, dataframe

```
cars <- data.frame(vehicle.type = c('Skoda Oktavia', 'Hyundai i40', 'Skoda Superb'))
```

How can i add the data from vehicle.type to two new columns(brand and model)? E.x: brand - Skoda; model - Octavia

Comment: No answer is acceptable for you?

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit after comment

You can separate your column based on the first whitespace using the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
cars %>%
  mutate(vehicle.type = str_replace(vehicle.type, "\\s", "|")) %>%
  separate(vehicle.type, c("brand", "model"), sep = "\\|")
```

Output:

```
    brand    model
1   Skoda  Oktavia
2 Hyundai      i40
3   Skoda   Superb
4 Hyundai Santa Fe
```

##### Data

```
cars <- data.frame(vehicle.type = c('Skoda Oktavia', 'Hyundai i40', 'Skoda Superb', "Hyundai Santa Fe"))
```

##### Old answer

You can `separate` your column using the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
cars %>%
  separate(vehicle.type, c("brand", "model"), " ")
```

Output:

```
    brand   model
1   Skoda Oktavia
2 Hyundai     i40
3   Skoda  Superb
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I noticed this data in my data frame "Hyundai Santa Fe" and i get a warning message "Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 4 rows [1005, 1073, 1140, 1649]". How should i update your code so it works for this name?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** This approach also works for the case you gave in a comment: `'Hyundai Santa Fe'`.

You might try `str_split_fixed` from package `{stringr}`:

```r
# data 
cars <- data.frame(vehicle.type = c('Skoda Oktavia', 'Hyundai i40', 
                                    'Skoda Superb', 'Hyundai Santa Fe'))

# approach
library(stringr)
cars[, c("brand", "model")] <- str_split_fixed(cars$vehicle.type, " ", 2)

#result
cars
#>       vehicle.type   brand    model
#> 1    Skoda Oktavia   Skoda  Oktavia
#> 2      Hyundai i40 Hyundai      i40
#> 3     Skoda Superb   Skoda   Superb
#> 4 Hyundai Santa Fe Hyundai Santa Fe
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(cars$vehicle.type), " ", fixed = TRUE))) |>
  cbind(cars) |>
  set_names(c("brand", "model", "vehicle.type"))
```

```
    brand   model  vehicle.type
1   Skoda Oktavia Skoda Oktavia
2 Hyundai     i40   Hyundai i40
3   Skoda  Superb  Skoda Superb
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is with `extract` (the regex allows for multiple 'words' in the `model` part):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
cars %>%
  extract(vehicle.type, 
          into = c("brand", "model"),
          regex = "(\\S+)\\s(.*)")
    brand    model
1   Skoda  Oktavia
2 Hyundai      i40
3 Hyundai Santa Fe
4   Skoda   Superb
```

Data:

```
cars <- data.frame(vehicle.type = c('Skoda Oktavia', 'Hyundai i40', 'Hyundai Santa Fe', 'Skoda Superb'))
```